Kotlin Multiplatform: how to add firebase dependancy to wasmJs module?
I struggle for quite a few days now with just adding Firebase to my KMP project.
I don't see any good example which uses Firebase for web within KMP.
When I try to add Firebase's setup suggested by the "get ready" Firebase's flow, I add it as CDN in 's <script type="module">, I still can't use any of Firebase classes within commonMain module. Or even wasmJsMain module.
When I try to add Firebase as a dependency to build.gradle.ktx file - it just does not pick that up.
What I tried:
sourceSets {
 ... 
   commonMain.dependencies {
   
   implementation("dev.gitlive:firebase-firestore:1.13.0") // does not work.
 ...
  }
}

I see there's a way to do it with npm install firebase. Will that work?
I can't yet tell since I have npm issues now with not finding some modules...
Well, why does such an easy task for Android environment turn out to be a headache to figure out for the web... Am I on the right path? Maybe there's indeed some great example.
Or maybe you have some better options for the goal of just storing a small DB with 2-3 tables? I need to create a small website, yet small needs, not quite a lot of time for just figuring out how on Earth I enable Firebase for the project and just fetch 10 rows of info :rolling-eyes:

Please [edit] your question title to explain the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is simply the useless repetition of the tags (which should not even be in the title at all) followed by the meaningless "Is it possible?" phrase. Your title should be clear and specific enough that a future site user who is skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. The title now conveys absolutely no useful information. You can find suggestions on writing a better title in [ask].

Google does not officially support WasmJS. GitLiveApp Firebase project is not an official library. WasmJS support is discussed in this thread: https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk/issues/440
